# Can not find ionic-tooltips module

Tags: ionic-framework, angular7

When i imported TooltipsModule from ionic-tooltips that time i am getting an error can not find ionic-tooltips module.
i installed "**npm i ionic-tooltips**" this library.

This is the link for the library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-tooltips

[here is an image for the import statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNkaS.png)

Comment: It would be useful if you could post actual code rather than image....however from image shown it seems that import is not correct since it has a red underline. Try deleting and letting IDE do the import for you.